Spring entity isn't created
I make a lot of entities in my project, all of them are created and visible in my database except one, while I do exactly the same as in the other classes. What can be the cause of this?
I made de fields, de constructor, getters and setters and made sure it's an Entity Class so I can't understand why it does not work.
There is a many to one relationship with an account cause an account can have multiple studyprogresses and a many to one with studies cause one study can have multiple studyprogresses.
@Entity
public class StudyProgress {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private int year;
    @ManyToOne
    private Account account;
    @ManyToOne
    private Study studies;

    public StudyProgress() {
    }

    public StudyProgress(int year, Account account) {
        this.year = year;
        this.account = account;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }



    public Study getStudies() {
        return studies;
    }

    public void setStudies(Study studies) {
        this.studies = studies;
    }
}



Please add the imports and the folder structure if possible.

In order to help you out we will need more details. Start by enabled debug mode on your application and check the logs at the moment you are trying to persist this entity. Then add the logs here. Goal is to see if any error is happening. Things to check: make sure the other entities exists. Does the table exists in the database? Is your application configured to create table at startup? There are too many things that can be happening for anyone to help.
